# Modify JSON data to output as single table in HTML

Tags: php, arrays, json, html-table, php-curl

I want to output a single html table that looks like the following from a JSON array:

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this with PHP cURL. I have to convert this to a class using the json_decode function. I just am unsure of how to perform this step.
Right now I have a PHP file that looks like this:

```
 <?php
 // Create curl resource
 $ch = curl_init();

 // Set url


 // Return the transfer as a string
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 // $output contains the output string
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

when I echo the output at the end, I get the array displayed to me in the browser:

Cleaner looking JSON array:

Any help on how to display this as a single html table like above using `json_decode` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is below answer working and is that the same what you needed ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know, if any changes needed

```
$json = '{  
  "categories":[  
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec"
   ],
    "series":[  
    {  
     "name":"Tokyo",
     "data":[  
        49.9,
        71.5,
        106.4,
        129.2,
        144.0,
        176.0,
        135.6,
        148.5,
        216.4,
        194.1,
        95.6,
        54.4
         ]
       },
      {  
     "name":"New York",
     "data":[  
        83.6,
        78.8,
        98.5,
        93.4,
        106.0,
        84.5,
        105.0,
        104.3,
        91.2,
        83.5,
        106.6,
        92.3
        ]
       },
     {  
     "name":"London",
     "data":[  
        48.9,
        38.8,
        39.3,
        41.4,
        47.0,
        48.3,
        59.0,
        59.6,
        52.4,
        65.2,
        59.3,
        51.2
       ]
      },
     {  
     "name":"Berlin",
     "data":[  
        42.4,
        33.2,
        34.5,
        39.7,
        52.6,
        75.5,
        57.4,
        60.4,
        47.6,
        39.1,
        46.8,
        51.1
     ]
    }
   ]
  }';

$jsondecode = json_decode($json);
$finarr = [];
foreach($jsondecode as $key => $val){
    if($key == 'categories'){
      $finarr['Month'] = $val;  
    }
    if($key == 'series'){
        foreach($val as $valkey => $value){
            $finarr[$value->name]= $value->data; 

        }

    }

}
echo '<pre>';print_r(json_encode($finarr));

//Output
{
  "Month": [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ],
  "Tokyo": [
    49.9,
    71.5,
    106.4,
    129.2,
    144,
    176,
    135.6,
    148.5,
    216.4,
    194.1,
    95.6,
    54.4
  ],
  "New York": [
    83.6,
    78.8,
    98.5,
    93.4,
    106,
    84.5,
    105,
    104.3,
    91.2,
    83.5,
    106.6,
    92.3
  ],
  "London": [
    48.9,
    38.8,
    39.3,
    41.4,
    47,
    48.3,
    59,
    59.6,
    52.4,
    65.2,
    59.3,
    51.2
  ],
  "Berlin": [
    42.4,
    33.2,
    34.5,
    39.7,
    52.6,
    75.5,
    57.4,
    60.4,
    47.6,
    39.1,
    46.8,
    51.1
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would like it to use the json_decode() function that when I run the file it displays as a simple html table like i pictured above...using a class if possible.

Comment: Can you explain briefly?

Comment: @skotienos13. Why don't you accept answer even though you got what you achieved, I am not talking about this question, The other question which you have asked. If this repeats, No  one will come forward to help you

Comment: I only asked 1 question, which was to display an html table out of the json array.

Comment: @skotienos13. In your profile under question tag, You can see questions, If its correct along with upvote, Just approve it too